# Jquery UI textarea dont have resize

Tags: jquery-ui

I put all like from example in `jquery-ui` website but I don't have resize icon on the bottom right corner of `textarea`. But I CAN resize if I put mouse little lower. Here is a picture:

[image: jquery-ui textarea]

X is a place where I can resize `textarea`. Where can be problem?

### UPDATE

[image: firebug]

Is this ok or not? In picture you can see that big picture is loaded, but that resize icon is in the bottom right corner of that picture. Is that crossed out means that resize icon is not loaded?

Big pic: http://postimg.org/image/d9au77xwp/

Comment: Sounds like there might be some CSS pushing the corner image out of view. I would suggest using firebug in firefox to analyse what CSS is going on in the page.

Comment: I'm not very good with css :) I just used their's css (jquery)

Comment: Whatever i change in css nothing happens.. With firebug i saw this classes: `ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se` but if i change any class nothing happens. I cleared my cache every time

Comment: i found!  But now resize icon it's not here just cursor :)

Comment: See if any of these classes is using an image. If so, make sure the image is there.

Comment: Also, if you are using several different bits of code from various places, it's worth checking for inherited styles (using firebug it tells you the stylesheet that any of the styles come from).

Comment: The crossed out styles normally means that property has been overwritten by another style. If you switch to the styles tab it will show the latest definitions at the top with where they come from next to each style, so you should be able to work out what is overwriting the background image for the icon.

Comment: Looks like the one at the top is being used with a localhost path ... that's most likely the problem. Are you looking at this on a live server?

Comment: no, everything is on localhost

Comment: So in the top background-image definition if you hover over the url do you see an image on that? It's using a sprite sheet, which is why you see all the icons in one image. So it's worth checking how they've isolated the single image - either with clipping rectangle or using overflow:hidden with a width and height set and offsetting the background position (like a little window with the background moving behind it). It's worth measuring the positions of the icons in photoshop and see if that correlates to the offset in the CSS (background-position), remembering it works in reverse